# Println null argument in java

Tags: java, string

One interviewer asked me this below question what is the output of the program.

But I try it in my end the line one compile but line two not compile what is the reason behind it.

Anyone can tell me please.

```
package swain.javainterviewhub.blogspot.in;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaInterviewHub {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str=null;
        System.out.println(str);//Line 1 Compile 
        System.out.println(null);/Line 2 Not compile
    }

}
```

What is null in real.Its string or charecter or integer.My question is what is null type.
Thanks
Sitansu

Comment: What error does the compiler give you? That will give you a hint as to the reason.

Comment: The method println(char[]) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream

Comment: The compiler can't distinguish in the second case if you mean `System.out.println((Object)null)` or `System.out.println((String)null)` or indeed `System.out.println((char[])null)`.  Note that there may be some other overloads of `println` that could take a `null` reference as well.

Comment: [3.10.7. The Null Literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line two doesn't compile because `System.out` is a `PrintStream` instance, and `PrintStream` has more than one `println` method that take a reference type argument (`println(String x)` and `println(char x[])`). When you pass a `null`, the compiler can't decide which of the overloaded methods to choose.

`System.out.println(str)` passes compilation since the type of the argument (`String`) matches only one of the overloaded versions of `println` - `println(String x)`.

Comment: It should be noted that you can fix this adding an explicit cast: `println((String)null)`.

Answer (score 2):

you can cast it to make it work

```
System.out.println((String)null);
```

Answer (score -1):

i Don't Why you are printing `Null` . you can Null As s `String` on Print Statement .
You Can Use Like That :

```
String str=null;
System.out.println(str);//Line 1 Compile 
System.out.println("null");Print Null
```